# Проблема установки Gulp на Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gulp, frontend

Второй деь пытаяюсь установить Gulp на  Linux Ubuntu.

Алгоритм дейсвтвий

```
 sudo apt install nodejs  
 sudo apt install npm
```

После установки.

```
nodejs  -v  output v8.10.0
npm     -v  output 3.5.2
```

Устанавливаю Gulp

```
npm  install --global gulp-cli
```

После установки  в папке проекта  устанавливаю `package.json`

```
 npm init --yes
```

После чего устанавливаю  Gulp  в проект

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```

В файле `package.json`  в `devDependencies`  добовляется `gulp` с версией .

При вводе комады  `gulp` в `shell`  пишется что `gulp` не установлен.

Помогите разобратся  заранее спасибо

Comment: консоль перезапускали после установки?

Comment: Нет не перезапускал ..?

Comment: попробуйте перезапустить)))

Comment: не получилось ..

Comment: ну хз на вид все правильно сделано

Comment: Установил  Gulp  так .` sudo  apt install gulp   output  CLI version 3.9.1 . `  но при пработе выводится ошыбки.

Comment: глобально то галп установлен?

Comment: Gulp глобально и локально (в папке проекта)  установлен  но при работе   вывыодится  ошыбки в косноль

Answer (score 0):

Так попробовал стал работать

Обновил `nodjs и npm`

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

После установки

```
nodejs --version  output v11.10.1
npm    --version  output 6.7.0
```

Установка  `Gulp`

```
sudo npm install --global  gulp-cli
```

После установки в папке проекта устанавливаю `package.json`

```
npm init --yes
```

После чего устанавливаю `Gulp` в проект

```
sudo npm install gulp  --save-dev
```

В файле `package.json` в `devDependencies` добовляется `gulp` с версией .

После чего  создаю файл gulpfile.js .В нем пишу тестовый скрипт.

```
  sudo  gulp  output  using ~ /public_html/project/gulpfile.js
                       starting
                       finishid
```

Но в проекте еше добавляется файл `package-lock.json`  подскажите предназначение .